# Spring Boot MockMvc Authentication Object Is Null

Tags: spring-boot, junit, junit5, spring-test, mockmvc

```
@DeleteMapping("/uri/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<RestResponseBody> delete(@PathVariable Long id, Authentication auth) {
     return ResponseEntity.ok(new RestResponseBody());
}
```

This is the controller, and the Authentication object is null when I use MockMvc. But, SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() is not null. I can get the authentication information from SecurityContextHolder, but not from the Authentication parameter.

Note: While not using the MockMvc, there is no problem.

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = TestApplication.class)
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_CLASS)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc(addFilters = false)
public class XTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    @Transactional
    @WithMyUser
    void deleteTest() throws Exception {

        MyUser principal = (MyUser) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

        MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.delete("/uri/{id}", 00000)
                                                   .with(authentication(SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()))
                                                                 .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                                                                 .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)).andReturn();

        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

The principal in the test class is not null. But when I send the request to the controller, the authentication parameter becomes null even if SecurityContextHolder is not null. What I am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.x/reference/html/test-mockmvc.html#test-mockmvc-setup

In order to use Spring Security with Spring MVC Test it is necessary to add the Spring Security `FilterChainProxy` as a `Filter`. It is also necessary to add Spring Security’s `TestSecurityContextHolderPostProcessor` to support `Running as a User in Spring MVC Test with Annotations`. This can be done using Spring Security’s `SecurityMockMvcConfigurers.springSecurity()`